# Perform a Sql Server Spatial Intersection against a table full of spatial features?

Tags: sql-server, spatial, intersect

I have a table in sql 2015 that has a geometry column and about 10,000 records. I want to test if a new record i am thinking about adding overlaps any of the existing records. 
I know that i can compare two features with STIntersects like this:

> DECLARE @a geometry; 
>   DECLARE @b geometry;
>
> SET @a = GEOMETRY::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-10277454.3014
>   4527261.7601, -10277449.1674 4527236.5722, -10277503.1433 4527245.177, -10277462.2333 4527281.9267, -10277454.3014 4527261.7601))',3857);
>
> SELECT @b = [Shape] FROM [GIS].[ggon].[blah] WHERE
>   OBJECTID = 4539;
>
> SELECT @a.STIntersects (@b);

But what if i wanted to compare @a to ALL of the features in the blah table?

If the result of the intersection above is 1 then i know that the @a geometry intersects the @b geometry which it does. That works. 
But if i change @b to be:

> SELECT @b = [Shape] FROM [GIS].[ggon].[blah]

then i get a 0 - which is not correct

> SELECT @a.STIntersects (SELECT [Shape] FROM [GIS_PL].[talon].[MDC_WM]);

also fails

Comment: where @a.intersects(myCol)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DECLARE @a geometry; DECLARE @b geometry;

SET @a = GEOMETRY::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-10277454.3014 4527261.7601, -10277449.1674 4527236.5722, -10277503.1433 4527245.177, -10277462.2333 4527281.9267, -10277454.3014 4527261.7601))',3857);

SELECT * FROM [GIS].[ggon].[blah] WHERE [Shape].STIntersects(@a) = 1